# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/radiantthemes-addons/custom-menu/class-radiantthemes-style-menu.php on line 61

```
'description' => empty( rt_get_menu() ) ? esc_html__( 'Custom menus not found. Please visit <b>Appearance > Menus</b> page to create new menu.', 'radiantthemes-addons' ) : esc_html__( 'Select menu to display.', 'radiantthemes-addons' ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by taking the value like this in variable

```
$description = empty( rt_get_menu() ) ? esc_html__( 'Custom menus not found. Please visit <b>Appearance > Menus</b> page to create new menu.', 'radiantthemes-addons' ) : esc_html__( 'Select menu to display.', 'radiantthemes-addons' );
```

and use it like this

```
'description' => $description,
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, after changing this still the same error will occur

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to store `rt_get_menu()` function return value in a variable like `$rt_get_menu = rt_get_menu();`
After the just replace your line code with follows -

```
'description' => empty( $rt_get_menu ) ? esc_html__( 'Custom menus not found. Please visit <b>Appearance > Menus</b> page to create new menu.', 'radiantthemes-addons' ) : esc_html__( 'Select menu to display.', 'radiantthemes-addons' ),
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, after changing this still the same error will occur